# C: Malloc Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am getting a segmentation fault when using malloc. When I uncomment the global COPY & LIST variables and comment out the malloc & free calls, the program runs as expected.

Am I mis-using malloc or free? 
If so, what is the proper usage of malloc & free?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1000000
//int LIST[MAX_LENGTH];
//int COPY[MAX_LENGTH];

/**
 * [main description]
 * Main function reads generated data and then measures run time (in seconds) of each 
 * sorting algorithm. Data is re-shuffled to its original state for each sort.
 * @param  argc
 * @param  argv
 * @return      [returns 0 on successful run]
 * O(n^2)
 */
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    void read(int*, int*);
    void refresh(int*, int*);
    void selectionSort(long, int*);
    void bubbleSort(long, int*);
    void insertionSort(long, int*);
    time_t start, finish;
    long length = 1000;
    int *LIST = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int *COPY = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    read(LIST, COPY);
    for (length = 1000; length <= MAX_LENGTH; length=length+33300) {
        //code omitted
        refresh(LIST, COPY);
        //code omitted
        refresh(LIST, COPY);
        //code omitted
        refresh(LIST, COPY);
        LIST = realloc(LIST, length * sizeof(int));
        COPY = realloc(COPY, length * sizeof(int));
    }
    free(LIST);
    free(COPY);

    return 0;
}
/**
 * [read description]
 * Reads data from stdin, and populates @LIST. 
 * Also populates @COPY, a copy of @LIST. 
 */
void read(int* LIST, int* COPY) {
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &LIST[i]);
        COPY[i] = LIST[i];
    }
}

/**
 * [refresh description]
 * Copies the contents of parameter from into parameter to. 
 */
void refresh(int *LIST, int *COPY) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        LIST[i] = COPY[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you find this code?

Comment: I wrote the code myself. I haven't included my sort functions.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C. If this is supposed to be C++, don't use `malloc` and avoid `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available

Comment: How does this even compile with the `malloc` version?  The `refresh` function references `LIST` and `COPY` but they are not even defined globally.

Comment: @cdhowie I think he just copy read and refresh function below main() but normally he keeps them above of main function.

Comment: @python That does not matter. The `LIST` and `COPY` names don't refer to anything from within `refresh()`, no matter whether the function is placed before or after `main()`. The compiler should be giving an error about this; if it doesn't then OP is posting different code than he is having problems with.

Comment: @cdhowie the code above is what I was having issues with. The compiler was not producing any warnings or errors - LIST and COPY are being passed to the refresh function from within main(). I realize it's poor style to have non-global variables with all-caps names, and I've made local changes to fix that.

Comment: hesham8: you should try with `-Wall -Wextra` flags when compile. @cdhowie I can't get your point. In my opinion, this code would work with `read(&LIST, &COPY)`. This is similar code where I didn't need global variables [link](http://pastebin.com/UkCTkFvi). I'm kind of new in C, so keep in mind I don't understand everything yet.

Comment: @hesham8 At the time I made the comment, the arguments to refresh were called `from` and `to` but you were referring to `LIST` and `COPY` in the function body. That version would never have compiled successfully. You have since updated the question to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trampling way out of bounds with the `refresh()` function.  The version I'm  looking at is:

```
void refresh(int *LIST, int *COPY) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        LIST[i] = COPY[i];
    }
}
```

You should pass in the number of items to copy and not use `MAX_LENGTH`.

```
void refresh(int n_items, int *LIST, int *COPY) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_items; i++) {
        LIST[i] = COPY[i];
    }
}
```

On a minor style note, you should usually reserve names in upper case for macros (with the known exceptions of `FILE` from `<stdio.h>` and `DIR` from `<dirent.h>` on POSIX systems; they are not usually macros).

Comment: Both you and @Dogbert were correct. I managed to fix my problem by changing it so that I only have one malloc call (no re-allocs) and specifying as @Dogbert suggested: `int *LIST = malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(int));`. By doing this, it also validated the refresh function.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in your `malloc` call. The lines below:

```
int *LIST=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * length);
int *COPY=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * length);
```

should be:

```
int *LIST=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
int *COPY=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
```

You are doing something similar with your `realloc` call. I'm not 100% what your intent is with the `realloc` calls, but it should probably be something like:

```
LIST = (int*)realloc(LIST, length * sizeof(int));
```

Alternatively, you could just define something to represent the size of a single element, since you're always working with `int` types throughout your code.

Comment: @Nullpointer Based on the `read()` function, no, he does not intend this.

Comment: @Nullpointer Then `LIST` and `COPY` should be of type `int**`, not `int*`.  Usually the pattern for using `malloc` is `T* p = malloc(sizeof *T * count)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin You mean `T* p = malloc(sizeof T * count);`

Comment: @cdhowie: I suspect he was thinking of `T *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * count);`, but you're right — the `sizeof(*T)` is wrong when T is the type.

Comment: Right, the type goes in `sizeof()` and the result is assigned to that plus one `*`: `int ** p = malloc(sizeof(int *) * count)` for example. @jamesdlin made the same mistake that OP made.

Comment: @cdhowie, @JonathanLeffler Oops, yes, I meant `sizeof *p`.  Arggh.  Brain fart. (`*T` makes no sense... that's what I get for trying to substitute in generic names...)